# Tagging individual pages of a PDF with ItextSharp C#

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, tagging

I am currently working with ITEXTSHARP 5.5.6.0

My goal is to add a Key to each page and have those persistent when I read the document again with another application.  I want to be able to keep track of every page individually (the key is unique, and comes from another source).

This is my import/write code:

```
 using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdfPath))
 {

        using (Document document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(pageNumber)))
        {

            PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(document, new System.IO.FileStream(outputPdfPath, System.IO.FileMode.Create));
            pdfCopyProvider.SetTagged();
            pdfCopyProvider.PdfVersion = PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7;

            PdfImportedPage importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, pageNumber, true);
            importedPage.SetAccessibleAttribute(PdfName.ALT, new PdfString("MYKEY"));
            pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);               
        }
 }
```

This is my read code:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms);
            copy.SetTagged();
            document.Open();
            for (int i = 0; i < pdfs.Count; ++i)
            {
                var pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfs[i]);
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
                int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int page = 0; page < n; )
                {
                    var importPage = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page, true);
                    var MyKey = importPage.GetAccessibleAttribute(PdfName.ALT);
                    if (MyKey != null)
                        //Do Something with KEY
                    copy.AddPage(importPage);
                }
            }
            document.Close();
            copy.Close();


            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

I am trying to add an accessibility ALT text.  Currently, I use that attribute on images, and all applications are set to leave those attributes untouched.

**The problem is that when I add the attribute this way, save it to a PDF file, and then read it on another process, the attribute is no longer there.**

I am open to other options, to resolve the problem of having a primary key per page, that i can assign, read and remove

I am *trying* to avoid adding a hidden field on each page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have little experience with iText programming or with c# so I'm ideal to answer your question :)

First of all, if all you want to do is mark a page and afterwards find it again, please **do not use** the accessibility features in the PDF. Accessibility is there for assistive devices, abusing those features isn't nice.

Especially because - if I understand correctly what you want to do - there is no need to do so. If you want to mark a page, you should look for the page dictionary, for example:

```
PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(file_content);
PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(i);
```

Copied from: http://goobbe.com/questions/8099416/how-to-get-the-userunit-property-from-a-pdffile-using-itextsharp-pdfreader

Once you have that dict, you can insert your own private key in there:

```
public void put(PdfName key, PdfObject object);
```

The value you assign is up to you, but if you want to follow the rules, you have to use a *second class PDF name* as the key. This is a key that consists of your developer prefix - which should be registered so it is unique and a private part. For example a key could look like:

```
FICL:PageNumber
```

In that case "FICL" is your developer prefix and "PageNumber" is your identification of the data you are adding.

To register a developer prefix, see the Adobe web site, for example here: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdfregistry_v3.pdf

Hope this helps.

PS: If anyone here knows who actually owns the "FICL" prefix and where the letters come from, I'll buy you a beer :)

Comment: Some prefixes were registered with Adobe *before* PDF was an ISO standard. These prefixes were registered under an NDA and Adobe doesn't have the right to disclose them. Hence the list can't be released to the public for legal reasons. Part of the list dates from *after* PDF was an ISO standard. That list can be made public, but it isn't because it would be misleading: it's only a small portion of the full list. In the meantime, I know that FICL was registered by Enfocus (Esko) by the chairman of the board of the iText Group. I've sent him a mail asking him what FICL stands for.

Comment: Answer from our chairman: Enfocus was originally founded using the name FirstClass. The name had to change because of a conflict with an existing trademark. However, in the meantime, FICL (FIrstCLass) was registered as prefix for second class names. How's that for technological archeology? :D

Comment: By the way: the second class prefix that was registered for iText is ITXT.

Comment: Bruno, using your chairman is cheating :) I owe you a beer but I think your chairman owns me own as well ;)

Comment: IT WORKS!!! so i need to do more testing, but i have add it to an individual page, then merge it with others and i have my tags as i need them  THANKS, up vote for both Great answer

Comment: As Reference CODE SNIPPED for 
SET KEY
pageDict.Put(new PdfName("FICL:PageNumber"), new PdfString("MYKEY"));

GET KEY
 var myKey = pageDict.GetAsString(new PdfName("FICL:PageNumber"));

Comment: Please don't use `FICL` as prefix unless you are affiliated to Esko (or Enfocus). The idea of the second class names is that every developer registers its own prefix and maintains its own names. You should not "hijack" another company's prefix.

Answer (score 2):

David's answer is correct and it's the answer that should be accepted. However, I'm adding an extra answer for the sake of completeness.

The OP's question is about adding an extra key to the page dictionary of *existing* pages in a PDF. If you want to add a key to a PDF that is built from scratch using iText, you can use the `addPageDictEntry()` method in [`PdfWriter`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html). This will add an entry to the page dictionary of the next page object that is created by a `PdfWriter` instance.

It's something that could be automated by using page events, for instance if you want to give each page a unique ID by adding a custom entry to the page dictionary of each page that is created with iText.

(This doesn't answer the OP's question because he's not using a `PdfWriter`, but this answer could be useful for other people with the same question in the context of creating PDFs from scratch.)